# Why use Ola Hallengren DatabaseBackup method with Idera SQLSafe?

Tags: sql-server, backup, ola-hallengren

We are planning to implement Ola Hallengren's Maintenance Solution in our environment.

Our organization on the other end, is planning to purchase Idera SQLSafe (requested a demo first).

I see a parameter @BackupSoftware = 'SQLSAFE' in Ola's solution.

Question:

1. With Idera SQLSafe tool installed, based on the parameter @BackupSoftware in Ola's solution, I assume even Idera SQLSafe can benefit by Ola's solution. Can I know how does it benefit? - Is it just the compression level?
2. When we have Ola's solution, is it really necessary for a 3rd party tool?

Answer (score 3):

Ola's solution blends with third party softwares

```
LITESPEED     LiteSpeed for SQL Server
SQLBACKUP     Red Gate SQL Backup Pro
SQLSAFE Idera SQL Safe Backup
```

It allows you to leverage automation and has a lot of flexibility in-terms of different parameters e.g. blocksize, compression, etc that you might end up writing when deploying the software to many machines.

See the comparison chart : https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqlsafebackup/best-sql-backup-software

Comment: (I have not tried Idera SQLSafe). So, using Idera SQLSafe is for centralized solution/reports/alerts, etc., where we still deploy Ola's solution on every server - correct?

Comment: You have to deploy Ola's solution to every server instance. Normally, I create a dba database e.g. dbautility and have it installed as part of server instance installation. That dbautility stores all the SPs for backup, restore (you can use sp_restoregene) or sp_blitz (from brent Ozar team), etc

Answer (score 1):

> When we have Ola's solution, is it really necessary for a 3rd party tool?

Ola's scripts have a lot of things, but they don't have a restore script. That means you're left to fend for yourself. One advantage of third party software is the ability to script and execute restores to a point in time rather more easily.

Comment: I used the script from following link and altered it a bit to meet our requirements, so we have restore scripts ready...Let me try out Idera SQLSafe and try out the Instant Restore option !!...https://jaredzagelbaum.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/automated-restore-script-output-for-ola-hallengrens-maintenance-solution/